# How to select all instances of selected region in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a shortcut key or single-step menu option to find and select all instances of a highlighted selection in Sublime Text?

Comment: I thought that this was a to the point, clear, complete and specific. It answered exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks for a real question. Have an upvote... :)

Answer (score 424, accepted):

On Mac OS you can use: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: I can not remember it. Some suggestion for good mnemotechnic? What `g` could stand for?

Comment: @andi `g`et all of them? :)

Comment: There are standard OS X commands for find next (⌘G) and find previous(⌘⇧G) in the Edit->Find menu. But I tend to think of them as get next and get previous so naturally ⌘^G is get all.

Comment: @andi `g`otta select'em all?

Comment: @andi "f" -> "find"  "g" -> "find next"
"g is _next_ to f"
"cmd+shift+f" -> "find all"  "cmd+ctrl+g" -> "get all"
nevemind, that doesn't help

Comment: this isn't case sensitive

Comment: This is why I love Sublime!

Comment: I don't know who invented pokemon `g`o. But we've gotta figure out how to get pokemon `g`o to the polls.

Comment: `G`angsta coding?

Comment: More keyboard shortcuts: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html

Answer (score 305):

On Windows/Linux press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: just want to put out there that is uses the same case sensitive settings as __find__ or __find and replace__. I kept changing the class name as well as the instance name. :\

Comment: @Mathias I've never understood the practice of using class and instance names that are identical in all but type case. I always feel like either the class name is too specific, or the instance name is too general and not descriptive enough.

Comment: You know how hard naming actually is. It might seem like an easy task but I find myself struggeling with good names for both classes and instances a lot. I think the "instance is lowercase class name"-thing kind of makes sense. I mean - it gives you the type of the variable on first glance. The only annoying thing is if you have multiple of `TextField`. You can't name all of them `textfield` of course. So I admit that in some cases it's not specific enough (like TextFields) but if you are talking about controllers, I think it makes perfect sense eg `articleController = new ArticleController()`

Comment: So in a way it really depends on the situation, but in general I think that the class name should already be a good description and therefore also fitting for the instance. BUT - obviously this is a question of tast much like: tabs vs spaces ... PS: Dear internet - I do not want to start another tabs vs spaces flame war here ... :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I highlight a section of code, Ctrl+I to start searching, borders around all search term within highlighted region, then Alt+F3, but it selects all matching terms in the file instead of just the region.

Comment: Alt-F3 for me opens up the menu at the top left corner (Linux Mint KDE)

Comment: @oli thank you - and wow that's an unbelievable amount of reputation for such a simple answer ;) kudos

Comment: Only highlights the text, does only select one occurence.

Comment: @oli alt+F3 seems to select all instances of the selected part. for example, when highlighting 'foo', it would also select the first part in foobar (foo)bar. Is there a way to select only full words?

Comment: Alt + f3, this works fine for me but is there any way where I can just replace the word in a selected/highlighted content?

Answer (score 26):

> On Windows/Linux press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

This worked for me on Ubuntu. I changed it in my "Key-Bindings:User" to something that I liked better though.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the defaults files, as they'll be overwritten on an update. Instead, copy the property to your "Key Bindings - User" file and edit it there, e.g. `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"], "command": "find_all_under" }`

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer, and would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @dbw - I agree with you, but to the best of my knowledge there's no rule on SO that discusses what to do with duplicate answers.

Comment: @dbw - It seems that the most appropriate thing to do with duplicate answers such as this one is to downvote them. So -1 from me. See this on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226562/228219

Answer (score 21):

On Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

However, you can reset any key any way you'd like using "[Customize your Sublime Text 2 configuration for awesome coding.](http://www.nerdi.net/blog/2012/02/05/customize-your-sublime-text-2-configuration-for-awesome-coding/)" for Mac.

---

On Windows/Linux:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

If anyone has how-tos or articles on this, I'd be more than happy to update.

Comment: your answer is useful to me:)

Answer (score 20):

Note:
You should not edit the default settings, because they get reset on updates/upgrades. For customization, you should override any setting by using the user bindings.

On Mac:

- Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Key Bindings-Default
- Sublime Text 3 > Preferences > Key Bindings

This opens a document that you can edit the keybindings for Sublime.

If you search `"ctrl+super+g"` you find this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+super+g"], "command": "find_all_under" },
```

Comment: But don't make changes on `default` config files, as they are replaced on update & upgrades. Use `user` key binding files instead @dcryan22

Comment: @ilhnctn Right, you shouldn't edit these. You should override them in the `user` keybindings. I just posted the `default` binding to show what the key combination was.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @ilhnctn. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 16):

In the other posts, you have the shortcut keys, but if you want the menu option in every system, just go to *Find > Quick Find All*, as shown in the image attached.

Also, check the other answers for key binding to do it faster than menu clicking.

[image: Sublime Text 3]

Answer (score 7):

Even though there are multiple answers, there is an issue using this approach. It selects all the text that matches, not only the whole words like variables.

As per "[Sublime Text: Select all instances of a variable and edit variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/sublime-text-select-all-instances-of-a-variable-and-edit-variable-name)" and the answer in "[Sublime Text: Select all instances of a variable and edit variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/sublime-text-select-all-instances-of-a-variable-and-edit-variable-name/18422707#18422707)", we have to start with a empty selection. That is, start using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> which would help selecting only the whole words.

Comment: This is great to know. `Alt+F3` without selection -> whole word. With selection -> precise match.