# sublime text3 : how to make multiple selection from the FIND result?

Tags: sublimetext3

When i put the keyword into the find box, all the matched string will be highlighted but they are not selected. So only 1 match will be selected using the find button.

I want all the matched string to be multiple selected. How can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162047/sublime-text-editor-how-to-select-all-instances-of-selected-region?rq=1

Comment: In addition to that, pressing `Find All` in the panel selects all of the matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime text editor: how to select all instances of selected region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162047/sublime-text-editor-how-to-select-all-instances-of-selected-region)